# RoR 4 belongs_to foreign_key not checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm a newbie in RoR and I'm trying to make a simple experiment. I want to have a User model and a Role model. Each user a single Role, but a single Role may refer to multiple Users.

So, here are my models:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :role
end
```

And here are migrations:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, index: true, unique: true, limit: 16
      t.integer :permissions, null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false, index: true,  unique: true, limit: 128
      t.string :password_digest, null: false, limit: 40
      t.string :password_salt, null: false, limit: 40
      t.string :screen_name, default: '', limit: 32
      t.belongs_to :role, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

What I want is to make it raise an exception when I try to connect user with a role that does not exist:

```
user = User.create(email: 'user@example.com', password_digest: 'pwd_dig',
                   password_salt: 'salt', role_id: 10)
```

Unfortunately this works and the new user is created, no matter that the role with id 10 does not exist.

So, how can I force foreign_key check here?

And another question about that. If I try to do like this:

```
user = User.create(email: 'user@example.com', password_digest: 'pwd_dig',
                   password_salt: 'salt', role: role)
```

it raises an exception because role does not have attribute user_id. There is no way to do like this, does it?

Comment: `has_many :users` proper pluralization is very important in Rails.

Comment: No, but it will fix a bunch of other future issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm a newbie in RoR

Welcome!!

---

```
#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :role

   validates :role_id, presence: true, on: :create
   validate :check_role, on: :create

   private

   def check_role
      errors.add(:role_id, "Role doesn't exist") unless Role.exists? role_id
   end
end
```

This will allow you the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
      @roles = Role.all
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :etc, :role)
   end
end

#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.email_field :email %>
   <%= f.collection_select :role_id, @roles, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Because you're new, I'll give you some info:

**1. Association**

Your association is slightly incorrect - you'll be best using a [`belongs_to/has_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

[image]

The `belongs_to` will assign the `foreign_key` in your `User` model, allowing you to both reference and validate against it.

-

**2. [Custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)**

Secondly, you'll be able to use a validation to check whether the `role` has been set correctly.

Each time a Rails model is saved, it calls a series of validators you've set -- allowing you to call such functionality as checking whether a role exists.

Comment: Hmm, `validate :check_role, on: :create` because the foreign key in the database will cause an update query to fail if `role_id` does not exist?

Comment: I'll leave the `on: :create` to give the OP some perspective on what he can use, I'd use your approach personally but since he's new he needs references

Comment: Ok, I see that it is possible to validate role existence in rails. But why it does not generate foreign key inside a database? I mean that role_id is just an integer column, without the foreign key constraint. That seems strange to me.

Comment: foreign key is an integer... I don't understand what you need from a foreign key column that would be any different than an integer?

Comment: I mean traditional RDBMS foreign key constraint so that DB validates role existence, not an application. Like this: FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id). I googled for that and found that it is not possible out-of-the-box, I need a Foreigner gem and a DB that it supports (https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner).

Comment: Could you not use PGSQL? I've not got a huge level of experience with this type of implementation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-fk.html

Comment: Well, I can use any RDBMS I want, it is just experiments for now. Actually everything I wanted to know whether it is possible or not to have such a column. It seems that it is impossible and Rails provides such functionality on its side. That's ok, I just wanted to check that I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add a custom validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  validate :existance_of_role

  private
    def existance_of_role
      if role_id && !Role.exists?(role_id)
        errors.add(:role, "must already exist.")
      end
    end
end
```

Also you need to use `belongs_to :role`. `has_one` would place the foreign_key in the relationship on the `Role` model instead of on the user.

- http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/

#### If the user must have a role.

Also if you want to enforce on the database level that the user has a role you would add a NOT NULL constraint to `users.role_id`.

Run: `rails g migration AddNotNullConstraintToUsers`

And then edit the migration file created:

```
class AddNotNullConstraintToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null(:users, :role_id, false)
  end
end
```

After running the migration you can change the validation so that it will add an error also when the role_id is nil.

```
private
  def existance_of_role
    errors.add(:role, "must already exist.") unless Role.exists?(role_id)
  end
```

You could do the same thing with `validates_presence_of :role` but that will not enforce that the Role is pre-existing.

Comment: Yeah, but I noticed I missed the part about belongs_to.

Comment: A question - what happens if `role_id` doesn't exist?

Comment: The record will still be inserted with nil.

Comment: Okay so some nice context between the two answers I guess (mine rquires `role_id`, your can be submitted without a role)

Comment: Correct, I did not assume that the User was required to have a role. Just that it should enforce that a user cannot have a non-existant role. Edited my answer a bit with some details about how to enforce that the user must have a role and changed the naming to line up with the built in validations.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this validator at your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :role

    validate :role_id_exists

    def role_id_exists
      return false if Role.find_by_id(self.role_id).nil?
    end
end
```